# Issue with Spring Rest @RequestMapping when negating params

Tags: spring, spring-rest, spring-web

I have two spring controller methods :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST,params = "!applicationId") //new customer
public OTPResponseDTO requestOTP( @RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO){
    return customerService.requestOTP(customerDTO);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST,params = {"idNumber","applicationId"}) //existing customer
public String requestOTP( @RequestParam(value="idNumber") String idNumber , @RequestParam(value="applicationId") String applicationId) {
    return customerService.requestOTP(idNumber, applicationId);
}
```

using `"!applicationId"` , I am expecting that when I call the url with `applicationId` parameter there that the second method will be called , but actually when I pass a request like this :

`{"idNumber":"345","applicationId":"64536"}`

The first method gets called

This is the part of the `params` paremeters documentation that I rely on :

> Finally, "!myParam" style expressions indicate that the specified
>   parameter is not supposed to be present in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually wasn't with negating the parameter, the issue was that I was sending `{"idNumber":"345","applicationId":"64536"}` in the POST body and I was expecting the variables to be mapped to the method parameters annotated with `@RequestParam` ... this is not correct ... `@RequestParam` only map URL parameters .... so the controller was trying to find the best match so it was using the first method as it contained `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just simply delete first request params?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestotp",method = RequestMethod.POST) //new customer
public OTPResponseDTO requestOTP( @RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO){
    return customerService.requestOTP(customerDTO);
}
```

Comment: didn't help actually